# How to get the "real-time" updates from an android mobile phone's clock?

Tags: android, time

I am creating an alarm clock application and I would like to have a small text-based representation of the actual time in "hh:MM:ss am/pm" format that would be in sync with the actual time of the mobile phone.

I tried searching around but nothing seemed to help me. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Android 4.2 (v17), you can use [TextClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html) to provide a formatted, always up to date text representation of the current time. For previous versions, you would need to create your own widget that controls updating the time (the [TextClock source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TextClock.java) may prove helpful).

Answer (score 2):

System.currentTimeinMillis() will give you the current real time accurately.

Then use a handler to trigger an update to your UI every second.